# Infinispan9 expiration lifespan with Camel

Tags: apache-camel, infinispan-9

I am using infinispan9 with camel 
infispan.xml

```
<distributed-cache name="myCache" mode="SYNC" start="EAGER">
    <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED" acquire-timeout="30000" concurrency-level="1000" striping="false"/>
    <!-- set lifespan to 1 hour in millisecond 3600000-->
    <expiration lifespan="120000" />
</distributed-cache>
```

In my camel route I am using:

```
<idempotentConsumer messageIdRepositoryRef="infinispanRepo">
    <header>CamelFileName</header>
        <setHeader headerName="fileExist">
        <simple>true</simple>
    </setHeader>
</idempotentConsumer>
<when>
    <simple>${header.fileExist} == null</simple>
    <!-- log duplicate-->
</when>
```

Now my concern is I have processed a file at 6:30:00 it processed success. I reprocessed the file at 6:31:00, it loged duplicate. that's fine. I am expecting the file to be successfully reprocessed after 6:32:00 but Failed and logged duplicate. What I observed is when ever the idempotentConsumer is verifying, the time is updated and I need to wait 2 sec after the last processed duplicate log.

All I want is to expire after first entry. Please help.

Comment: Can you explain just a little bit better what your problem is

Comment: Infinispan expiration lifespan if set to 2 sec. After 2 sec it should expire. But between 2 sec if you process again , it log duplicate but the expiry starts from the last access not from the initial entry

Comment: Tried enable skipDuplicate="true" but still it consider last access  of the key as  expiry rather than first entry time as expiry